# MS Edge: Unable to get browser version via Capabilities.getVersion()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have a Selenium project using Java that uses different browsers. I'm trying to introduce MS Edge, but having trouble using the getVersion() method from Capabilities. Below is a code snippet from a method that initializes the browser. WebDriver "driver" is declared at the beginning of the class.

```
            if(strBrowser.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge"))
        {
            String FileName=m1.get("TOOLS_PATH").toString()+"//MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";
            System.out.println("Full path to Edge executable: " + FileName);

            File edgeDriver = new File(FileName);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", edgeDriver.getAbsolutePath());  

            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.edge();

            driver = new EdgeDriver(caps);  //launches Edge browser


        }


        Capabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();           
        String browserName = caps.getBrowserName();
        String browserVersion = caps.getVersion().toString();
```

During debugging in ecliipse, when I hover on the 'caps' object after initializing it, it shows me the following:
Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, **browserVersion=25.10586.672.0**, platformVersion=10, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, takesScreenshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows, platform=ANY}]

The string browserName comes out to be "MicrosoftEdge", but browserVersion comes out empty. I'd expect that it'd come out to be "25.10586.672.0"

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach

```
String browser_version = null;
    Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) browserDriver).getCapabilities();
    String browsername = cap.getBrowserName();
    // This block to find out IE Version number
    if ("internet explorer".equalsIgnoreCase(browsername)) {
        String uAgent = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) browserDriver).executeScript("return navigator.userAgent;");
        System.out.println(uAgent);
        //uAgent return as "MSIE 8.0 Windows" for IE8
        if (uAgent.contains("MSIE") &amp;&amp; uAgent.contains("Windows")) {
            browser_version = uAgent.substring(uAgent.indexOf("MSIE")+5, uAgent.indexOf("Windows")-2);
        } else if (uAgent.contains("Trident/7.0")) {
            browser_version = "11.0";
        } else {
            browser_version = "0.0";
        }
    } else
    {
        //Browser version for Firefox and Chrome
        browser_version = cap.getVersion();// .split(".")[0];
    }
    String browserversion = browser_version.substring(, browser_version.indexOf("."));
    return browsername + " " + browserversion;
```

Answer (score 0):

In firefox and Edge you need to specify the field name that you require its value - so please do like this:

```java
Capabilities capabilities = ((RemoteWebDriver) webDriver).getCapabilities();
String browserVersion = capabilities.getCapability("browserVersion").toString();
```